# Редактируемый массив определённого типа

Tags: массивы, objective-c, xcode, ios7

Как создать редактируемый массив типа SKShapeNode или int?
Если например с BOOL, то делаю так:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

И могу добавлять или править значения:

```
[array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
array[i] = @NO;
```

Но как создать другого типа?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В изменяемый массив можно добавлять любые объекты.

Свойство у объекта, находящегося в массиве можно поменять так:

```
((SKShapeNode *)array[0]).position = CGPointMake(20, 20);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[array addObject:@(123)]; // тоже, что и [NSNumber numberWithInteger:123] или number with любой какой надо скалярный тип
```

Ну и в случае с объектами тоже самое:

```
[array addObject:playerNode];
array[i] = [SKShapeNode node];
```

На самом деле не очень понятно в чем вопрос

Comment: Если я делаю:
  SKShapeNode *sprite = [SKShapeNode node];
То я с лёгкостью могу изменить свойство position, а когда пишу:
  NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  array[0] = [SKShapeNode node];
То при попытке изменения свойства, то есть:
  array[0].position = CGPointMake(20,20);
То получаю ошибку: Property 'position' not found on object of type 'id'

Comment: @97mik array[0] вернет вам id - указатель на произвольный (любой) объект в терминах Objective-C. Это связано с тем, что NSArray/NSMutableArray, как уже было сказано выше, могут хранить в себе объекты любого типа. Воспользуйтесь приведением типов. Самое банальное решение:
((SKShapeNode *) array[0]).position = CGPointMake(20, 20);